# Corresponding flow on cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, tangent-bundle, co-tangent-space

I have an exercise where it states:

Let $Y:Q \rightarrow TQ$ be a complete vector field with flow $\varphi_t$. Let
$X : T^{*}Q → T(T^{*}Q)$ be the vector field generating the corresponding flow
$\Phi_t$ on $T^{*}Q$.

Now I don't what is meant by "corresponding flow", how is this flow defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is talking about the cotangent lift of the flow on $Q$: for any diffeomorphism $f:Q\to Q$, there's a corresponding cotangent lift $T^*f:T^*Q\to T^*Q$, defined by
$$
T^*f(\alpha) := \alpha\circ T(f^{-1})
$$
(so $T^*f$ maps $T^*_qQ$ to $T_{f(q)}^*Q$). Apply this to the flow $\varphi_t$ generated by $Y$, i.e. $\Phi_t = T^*\varphi_t$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I don't quite understand yet, what $T$ is here. What is meant by $T(f^{-1})$?

Comment: $T(f^{-1})$ is the differential of $f^{-1}$ (sometimes it's written $d(f^{-1})$ or $(f^{-1})_*$). To be really precise, one should probably include the basepoints (which I will do next comment).

Comment: For any smooth $\varphi:Q\to Q$,  $T_q\varphi:T_qQ\to T_{\varphi(q)}Q$ is defined by $(T_q\varphi(X_q))(g) := X_q(g\circ \varphi)$, where $g\in C^\infty(Q)$ and $X_q\in T_qQ$. If $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, we can also define $T^*_q\varphi:T^*_qQ\to T^*_{\varphi(q)}Q$ by $T^*_q\varphi(\alpha_q) := (T_{\varphi(q)}\varphi^{-1})^*\alpha_q = \alpha_q\circ T_{\varphi(q)}\varphi^{-1}$, where $\alpha_q\in T^*_qQ$. The cotangent lift of $\varphi$ is the map $T^*\varphi:T^*Q \to T^*Q$ constructed from combining all such maps $T^*_q\varphi:T^*_qQ\to T_{\varphi(q)}^*Q$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! I was only familiar with the notation $df^{-1}$